# How to assign categories to a message using MailKit

Tags: c#, email, mailkit

I am using MailKit to read email messages from an inbox based on an [UID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) ([IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol)) which is working fine. However, I do not find an option to set the category to an email using MailKit programmatically.

I do see an option to set custom flags using the below code. However, this does not seem to be working as we cannot visualize the status of the emails.

```
var customFlags = new HashSet<string>();
                customFlags.Add("$Testing");
inbox.AddFlags(UniqueId.Parse(uid), MessageFlags.None, customFlags, true);
```

I am looking for something on how we can set the below category to email message using MailKit only.

Client: Imap , 
Mail Box: O365

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [Jazb stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717048/how-to-assign-categories-to-a-message-using-mailkit/69717701#69717701), IMAP does not have a concept of "categories" and it is up to the client to find alternative means of storing this state.

I'm not sure whether [Office 365](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_365) supports storing custom keywords (AKA custom flags) or not, but you *could* create a test folder and in that folder add six messages, one for each category, giving them subjects that would easily clue you in to what category you are assigning each of them (e.g., "Subject: Blue category").

Then use MailKit to Fetch the `MessageSummaryItems.Flags | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope` data:

```
var items = folder.Fetch (0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Flags | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope);
foreach (var item in items) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Office 365 uses the {0} keyword to designate the {1}", item.Keywords.FirstOrDefault (), item.Envelope.Subject);
}
```

You will get output like this:

```
Office365 uses the $MailLabel1 keyword to designate the Blue category
Office365 uses the $MailLabel2 keyword to designate the Green category
Office365 uses the $MailLabel3 keyword to designate the Orange category
Office365 uses the $MailLabel4 keyword to designate the Purple category
Office365 uses the $MailLabel5 keyword to designate the Red category
Office365 uses the $MailLabel6 keyword to designate the Yellow category
```

Once you know the real name of the keyword (which may or may not be "$MailLabel1"), then you can set the keywords via:

```
var keywords = new HashSet<string> () { "$MailLabel1" };
folder.AddFlags (uid, MessageFlags.None, keywords, true);
```

Comment: I have added a category to message and tried to fetch MessageSummaryItems.Flags. It is returning a null value for a message that has added a category.

Comment: Then it sounds like Outlook is not using keywords to store that state. It is probably storing that locally instead.

Comment: not correct - it is persisting them using keywords! You can find them when .GetMessage() under Headers.Keywords

Answer (score 0):

IMAP does not have a concept of categories or styles.

This is up to the user's mail client to synthesize by either setting custom flags on the message(s) (assuming that the IMAP server supports custom flags) or by just storing those attributes somehow locally on the user's desktop (or mobile device).

Comment: So how can label a message in O365 using mail kit ?

Comment: you can't using mail kit...